# BCryptPasswordEncoder in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am working on authentication module in spring and facing authentication failure by using **BCryptPasswordEncoder** as follow's
I **login successfully** through **admin account** and create a dummy user. then i **successfully login** through **dummy user** and logout as well.
after checking two accounts user (admin, user), when i try to login through any user i got **login failure** error.

Note: if i don't use any password encryption scheme then my module work fine.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" username-parameter="custom_username" 
        password-parameter="custom_password"
        default-target-url="/index"
        always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout=true"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/hrm/*" access="ROLE_HRM, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/leave/*" access="ROLE_HRM, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index**" access="ROLE_HRM, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_HRM, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">        
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="12" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>

        <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>

        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select app_user.username, role.name from app_user
                                           join app_user_role on app_user.id = app_user_role.users_id
                                           join role on app_user_role.roles_id = role.id
                                           where app_user.username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from app_user where username = ?" />

    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: What is the Exception, Status code you get for failed attempts?

Answer (score 0):

It's lack of information provided in your question, but you can try following:

1. Check if user passwords stored in encrypted way in you DB;
2. Put breakpoint in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication() method and make few debug steps. Here you can realize whats actually wrong in your workflow.

Please, provide additional information(Status Code, Error Message, etc) to receive more accurate assistance. Thanks

Comment: i don't received any Exception, just get custom error message as Invalid username and password. i following given link for authentication 
https://github.com/jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator

Comment: What status code you received when you send request for authentication?